# Tensorflow subclassing issue

Tags: tensorflow, subclassing, resnet

I have a resnet model, defined by the following class:

```
class ModelResNet(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ModelResNet, self).__init__()
        self.resBlock1 = ResBlock(num_filters=32)
        self.resBlock2 = ResBlock(num_filters=32)
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu')
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
        x = self.resBlock1(input_tensor, training=training)
        x = self.resBlock2(x, training=training)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)

        # Option 1
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)

        # Option 2
        # x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(x)
        # x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')(x)
        return x
```

When I call ModelResNet2.fit(), everything works great!
But, if I replace Option1 by Option2 in the "call" method, I get the following error:

ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
python-BaseException

Not sure I understand where the issue comes from.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When calling:

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(x)
```

you are creating a dense layer which will be immediately destroyed (after you exit call() method). It doesn't make sense - you will not be able to train.

Tensorflow is not able to create a graph of layers with such calls. So it prohibits them.